# Open url and fill form automatically

Tags: scripting, url

I'd like to create a script to open an url and fill some forms. I don't want to save the form data on the browser, so I think that this script would be a good solution for me.

Any help?

I know how to open the url, just calling `firefox url` on terminal.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use curl or wget to send POST data to a web page.

Comment: There are many possible tools to do this. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: See [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.fill)

Comment: @MichaelHampton, almost every day I have to check some informations filling 2 forms with personal data. But I don't want to save the data in my browser for privacy. So I'd like to execute a command on the terminal and get the site with the forms filled. Thanks.

Comment: With appropriate encryption, your browser (depending on the browser) may have better encryption and security for stored forms than the plaintext script you'll be writing to pre-fill the forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity.
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/xdotool.1.html